# Android app rejected due to background Location

Tags: android, location

I  have submit my android app 2 time in play store.But app is rejected with Reason of your app use BACKGROUND_LOCATION.After first rejection i removed the BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission from Android-manifest file.Again i submitted the app in play store than again rejected with same reason and Not meet with privacy policy.

```
App used  these permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
```

I removed this permission

So this is Again and again happening please suggest me what i can do.

Thanks & Regards
Umesh sharma

Comment: is your app track location in the background? if so, then you have to give proper explanation to google  play store.

Comment: Yes i have given proper resign and display the custom dialog before accept the location  permission.
Like------We need to access your Location to provide you better experience of the restaurants nearby.We only use the location when you are actively using the app.

Comment: Do you have a privacy policy? And moreover, if the location is accessed only when the user is using the app, why do you bother accessing *BACKGROUND_LOCATION*?

Comment: Yes i have privacy policy link. I removed the 
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION" />

Comment: Please take a look at my edited answer below, and it should be marked as accepted if helpful.

Answer (score 2):

1. if you are uploading it to some other channel at Google Play Console (e.g. alpha, beta, test), You need to upload the build to production channel and wait for google to review your build, also see **Pre-Launch Report Overview** section for errors if their remains some (possibly).
   [image]
2. And to resolve Background location permission issue you need to do the following steps as suggested by [Android Developer Officials](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#evaluate):

- If you find that your app accesses location in the background, consider taking the following actions:

  - Evaluate whether background location access is critical to the core functionality of the app.
    If you don't need location access in the background, remove it.
  - If your app targets **Android 10 (API level 29)** or higher, remove the [ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION permission](https://developer.android.com/training/location/receive-location-updates#request-background-location) from your app's manifest. When you remove this permission, all-the-time access to location isn't an option for the app on devices that run Android 10.
  - Make sure the user is aware that your app is accessing location in the background. This is especially important for cases that aren't obvious to users.
  - If possible, [refactor your location access logic](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/oreo/background-location-limits#tuning-behavior) so that you request location only when your app's activity is visible to users.

[Reference](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background#evaluate)